# How to perform batch select and update documents from cocuhbase using java?

Tags: couchbase

Can you please let me know whats the best way to bulk get and upsert documents from cocuhbase using java ? Can I use N1QL ? Please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use batching with RXJava

```
public List<JsonDocument> bulkGet(final Collection<String> ids) {
return Observable
    .from(ids)
    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<JsonDocument> call(String id) {
            return bucket.async().get(id);
        }
    })
    .toList()
    .toBlocking()
    .single();
}



public void updateDocuments(Collection<JsonDocument> documents) {
    Observable.from(documents).flatMap(new Func1<JsonDocument, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<JsonDocument> call(final JsonDocument docToInsert) {
            return bucket.async().upsert(docToInsert);
        }
    }).last().toBlocking().single();
}
```